# Is STAThread attribute a requirement or recommendation?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I wrote managed extension for AutoCAD. When AutoCAD loads an extension it launch some `IExtensionApplication.Initialize()` method. I need this method would be launched in the main `Thread` of application. Is it enough to set the `STAThread` attribute for this method for this purpose? Is this attribute a *requirement* or *recommendation*?

Comment: It's a requirement, i.e. it ensures that the Main() thread will be launched as STA.

Comment: Its neither, its an indication to the compiler that the code uses single threaded apartment. So its a command *to the compiler* but it has no effect on anything that loads it unless the code has special handling characteristics for it. `STAThread` also has no effect on any other method than the entry point of an application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @RonBeyer I think it's the .Net runtime that looks for this attribute, rather than the compiler using it (other than the compiler decorating the method with that attribute as it would any other attribute).

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, I meant the runtime, not the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [STAThread] attribute only works on the Main() entrypoint of a standalone executable program.  It is a *promise* you make to the operating system, telling it that the main thread of your program is "well-behaved".  It must pump a message loop and never block.  Breaking the promise causes hard to diagnose misbehavior, deadlock is common.

None of this applies when you write an AutoCAD extension.  You did not create the thread, AutoCAD did.  You can't make any promises, it is AutoCAD that has to implement them.  Nor is it a "main thread", that's a term that can only apply to a standalone program.

The thread that calls your extension is almost certainly already a single-threaded apartment, you can use Thread.GetApartmentState() in your code to double-check.  STA is a requirement for a thread that displays UI, something that you very commonly do in an extension.

Answer (score 2):

STA is a threading apartment policy for COM objects.
This threading policy is needed for many UI object that have an underlying implentation with COM objects.
That is why the main thread in a windows forms application is set to STA when you create a new project.

If you are not using any COM object that require the STA policy then you dont need that.